# Network and Disk IO outage on Google VM (europe-west1-b)

Tags: google-compute-engine

### **Question:**

How do we work out whether this problem was something we have done in our application or a problem with the Google platform?

### **Steps Taken:**

1. Checked the platform logs and there are no signs of VM migration.
2. Checked the Google Cloud Status Dashboard and there are no signs of any outages.

### **Detailed Description Of The Problem:**

We experienced a network and disk IO outage at approximate 8:37:40 UTC on Sunday 16th October. Here is a summary (see logs below for details):

1. [08:37:40] :- Our application experiences a DNS problem
2. [08:37:43] :- sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] abort - reported in syslog
3. [08:37:43] :- Over 5 minutes of kernel 'task blocked for more than 120 seconds' messages
4. [08:43:10] :- sd 0:0:1:0: device reset - reported in syslog
5. [08:43:10] :- three errors in google scripts (I think network related)
6. [08:43:11] : Our application recovers.

**[Our application log]**

```
I|2016-10-16|08:37:09.271|ALM          Finished processing alarms
W|2016-10-16|08:37:40.165|RC           Exception: DNS error: Temporary DNS error while resolving: www.googleapis.com
W|2016-10-16|08:37:47.218|BP           Exception: DNS error: Temporary DNS error while resolving: www.some-domain.com
I|2016-10-16|08:43:11.138|DB           line 1127: HWMDatabase::virtual void HWMDatabase::run() - Elapsed: 357999
I|2016-10-16|08:43:11.149|PE.CON       onTimeoutNotification 185.3.54.28:9161
```

**[Linux syslog]**

```
Oct 16 08:37:43 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151118.601288] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] abort
Oct 16 08:41:07 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151321.937381] INFO: task kworker/u4:1:29 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
...
Oct 16 08:41:07 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151322.089136] INFO: task jbd2/sda1-8:104 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
...
Oct 16 08:41:07 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151322.245617] INFO: task rs:main Q:Reg:414 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
...
Oct 16 08:41:07 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151322.481381] INFO: task hwm_master:7791 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
...
Oct 16 08:41:07 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151322.616600] INFO: task hwm_master:7802 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
...
Oct 16 08:41:07 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151322.861420] INFO: task cron:18904 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
...
Oct 16 08:41:08 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151323.051763] INFO: task cron:18905 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
...
Oct 16 08:42:53 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151428.634159] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] abort
Oct 16 08:42:53 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151428.638435] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] abort
Oct 16 08:42:53 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151428.642497] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] abort
Oct 16 08:42:53 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151428.646611] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] abort
Oct 16 08:42:53 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151428.650844] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] abort
Oct 16 08:42:53 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151428.655165] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] abort
Oct 16 08:42:53 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151428.659332] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] abort
Oct 16 08:42:53 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151428.663459] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] abort
Oct 16 08:42:53 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151428.667794] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] abort
Oct 16 08:42:53 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151428.671939] sd 0:0:1:0: [sda] abort
Oct 16 08:43:08 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151443.169478] INFO: task jbd2/sda1-8:104 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
...
Oct 16 08:43:08 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151443.328262] INFO: task ntpd:393 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
...
Oct 16 08:43:08 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151443.527233] INFO: task rs:main Q:Reg:414 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
...
Oct 16 08:43:10 hwm-node-1 kernel: [151445.559469] sd 0:0:1:0: device reset
Oct 16 08:43:10 hwm-node-1 rsyslogd-2007: action 'action 18' suspended, next retry is Sun Oct 16 08:43:40 2016 [try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2007 ]
...
Oct 16 08:43:10 hwm-node-1 google-ip-forwarding: ERROR GET request error retrieving metadata.#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 159, in _HandleMetadataUpdate#012    metadata_key=metadata_key, recursive=recursive, wait=wait)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 134, in _GetMetadataUpdate#012    response = self._GetMetadataRequest(metadata_url, params=params)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 50, in Wrapper#012    response = func(*args, **kwargs)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 97, in _GetMetadataRequest#012    return request_opener.open(request, timeout=self.timeout*1.1)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open#012    response = self._open(req, data)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open#012    '_open', req)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain#012    result = func(*args)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open#012    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1200, in do_open#012    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1111, in getresponse#012    response.begin()#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 444, in begin#012    version, status, reason = self._read_status()#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 400, in _read_status#012    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline#012    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)#012timeout: timed out
Oct 16 08:43:10 hwm-node-1 google-accounts: ERROR GET request error retrieving metadata.#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 159, in _HandleMetadataUpdate#012    metadata_key=metadata_key, recursive=recursive, wait=wait)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 134, in _GetMetadataUpdate#012    response = self._GetMetadataRequest(metadata_url, params=params)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 50, in Wrapper#012    response = func(*args, **kwargs)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 97, in _GetMetadataRequest#012    return request_opener.open(request, timeout=self.timeout*1.1)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open#012    response = self._open(req, data)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open#012    '_open', req)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain#012    result = func(*args)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open#012    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1200, in do_open#012    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1111, in getresponse#012    response.begin()#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 444, in begin#012    version, status, reason = self._read_status()#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 400, in _read_status#012    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline#012    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)#012timeout: timed out
Oct 16 08:43:10 hwm-node-1 google-clock-skew: ERROR GET request error retrieving metadata.#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 159, in _HandleMetadataUpdate#012    metadata_key=metadata_key, recursive=recursive, wait=wait)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 134, in _GetMetadataUpdate#012    response = self._GetMetadataRequest(metadata_url, params=params)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 50, in Wrapper#012    response = func(*args, **kwargs)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/google_compute_engine/metadata_watcher.py", line 97, in _GetMetadataRequest#012    return request_opener.open(request, timeout=self.timeout*1.1)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open#012    response = self._open(req, data)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open#012    '_open', req)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain#012    result = func(*args)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1227, in http_open#012    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1200, in do_open#012    r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1111, in getresponse#012    response.begin()#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 444, in begin#012    version, status, reason = self._read_status()#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 400, in _read_status#012    line = self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 476, in readline#012    data = self._sock.recv(self._rbufsize)#012timeout: timed out
```

Answer (score -1):

This error usually is caused by a throttle. This could be caused by disk size or a high increase of disk I/O. You should try either increasing the size of the PD or [using an SSD](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance) to improve performance.

Comment: This is done on a virtual machine run by Google - swapping drives is not possible here